# Is it safe to splice these cords with tape instead of a terminal?

Tags: electrical

In the image below, you can see that I have two cords spliced together with a terminal block, all covered in a black piece of plastic. As the cover is not very attractive, and too bulky to easily hide, I'd like to just get rid of it, tape the individual cords together, and hide them in a small cable tray.

On the right side, there's a 60W lamp, on the left side is a three-way splice with the power source and another lamp.

I'm a complete beginner in this area, so my question is simple: is this safe to do?

[image: joined cords]

Comment: What is at the other end of each cord?

Comment: I have added that info to the question. Also, my native language isn't English, and google translate helped me write the question. Some terms may be "odd" or just incorrect. Please let me know, so I can improve my vocabulary. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, I would not do that.

- First the one cord has a ground wire apparently not being picked up by the second cord.
  They both should have the ground wire.
- Secondly it is not a safe procedure to splice a 120 VAC line without
  it being protected in an approved box.
- Third the splice should be made with an approved connector, such as a wire nut or crimp.

The best way would be to replace the entire cord with one continuous wire.

Comment: +1 for the answer but couldn't that be a double insulated appliance with a standard three pin cord? or is that a no no to?

Comment: +1, part of the function of the device is stress relief which tape does not supply.

Comment: @UNECS - I can't remember ever seen a double insulated appliance with a three prong plug. One reason for the double insulation is so it does not require a ground. If it did have a ground, I'm sure you should not defeat it. The OP did not state what the load was, therefore I assume it should be grounded.

Comment: If the nongrounded cable is original to the device there is no problem with grounding. Also it is probably 240 VAC as the OP is from Europe (According to the associated Drupal account).